# Circular pipe in Windows command line

Tags: pipe

Given two applications A and B, is there a way to invoke them in Windows such that the standard output of A goes to the standard input of B and the standard output of B goes to the standard input of A?

Comment: That would be called _bi-directional_, not _circular_. It would probably help if you mention whether your target is the regular windows command line, some other command interpreter, or a program written in a specific language which you have on your mind.

Comment: @ClassStacker   what's the difference between bidirectional and Circular?

Comment: I suppose there may be a way to have e.g. a file piped to A which outputs to B and B's output goes to that file.. i'm not sure whether A would get the update though

Comment: @barlop A circle would be A -> B -> C -> A (identical instance as at the start), no? The [standard term for what the OP wants is `bi-directional`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28software%29) so let's use it.

Comment: I would have thought that people commenting would at least do a bit of research upfront (given that the OP did not do it by himself) but since that's not the case: There's no way to do this on the standard Windows command line, while its [relatively easy to achieve it programatically](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) (and also possible by using process wrappers).

Comment: What @barlop might mean by "piping from and to a file at the same time" is possible only with _named pipes_ but unfortunately, Windows does not allow their command-line control out of the box.

Comment: @ClassStacker well "out of the box" linux is just a kernel so doesn't allow for much either.  Nobody sane is using windows with a rule of no 3rd party software.  If you have the mkfifo command in mind. (you probably have used it before but I haven't.. i've just heard of it and it rang a bell).  There's cygwin and gnuwin32.  I see that gnuwin32 the coreutils package, has mkfifo..and most likely so does cygwin.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32303/discussion-between-barlop-and-class-stacker).

Comment: @ClassStacker: I disagree with your terminology.  A ↔ B would be bi-directional, but the user is asking for A → B → A (identical instance as at the start), which is circular.  And I don’t see anything in the Wikipedia reference that supports your claim.

Comment: @G-Man 1) You don't explicitly mention which terminology you deem correct. 2) Please explain to me the difference between "A -> B _and_ B -> A" (identical instances of A and B) and "A <-> B". I would only accept "circular" if at least three instances are involved, because only then an effective difference between _circular_ and _bi-directional: results. 3) Did you try `Ctl`-`F` `circular` and `bi-directional` on the WIkipedia page? ...

Comment: @G-Man  4) Did you try a web search for `circular pipe` and `bi-directional pipe`? It gives you the idea which of the terms is used for this scenario. Actually I believe that "circular pipes" are nowhere to be found because there's no use case for them. 5) You may prefer any term you like, but Q&A is about understanding each other, so a common terminology, based on established definitions, helps a lot in my view.